# Can I drop email software if only using external SMTP?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I have a dedicated server hosting 2/3 web apps (web-server + SQL server among other things) on Debian.

Now from time to time theses web apps send mails to their respective users using SMTP services like SendGrid.

I'm planning on rebuilding a new server config.

The only thing about email I want this server to do is: letting web apps send email through external SMTPs.

I don't want the server from acting as SMTP server, nor POP or IMAP. To be clear, if I could completely **drop email support from the software stack** of this server, that would be awesome.

- Is this possible?
- What is mandatory?
- What is irrelevant for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. What you need is an Mail Transfer Agent, that provides a sendmail interface and is able to relay your mails to an external SMTP server. There exist tools, that exactly fit that need. One of them is [nullmailer](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/nullmailer), another one [esmtp](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/esmtp). Its configurations are of course very simple; the only thing needed is the information about the SMTP server to use, and is asked for on package installation.

Comment: If the software used for the web app can send direct (e.g. PHP) even the MTA can be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a local MTA, that can act as a fail-safe mechanism while your external SMTP provider is down/suffering from poor deliverability.